# An input field getting required when another field is not null

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form with multiple rows with the pair of Product and quantity input fields. I want quantity field to be required when the product field is not null in the same row. I have used the Jquery function which is shown below. But it is not working properly. Hope someone will help me.

```js
$('.productSelect').change(function () {

  var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
  var numberPart = elementID.split("t", 2);

  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity'+ numberPart).prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

```html
   <form role="form" action="#" method="post" role="form" id="orderform">             

                            <tr>

                              <td><select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product1" style="width: 100%" id="product1">
                                <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
                                <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
                                <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
                                <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>

                              </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" type="text" /></td>

                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td><select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product2" style="width: 100%" id="product2">
                              <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
                              <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
                                <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
                                <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity2" id="quantity2" type="text" /></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td><select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product3" style="width: 100%" id="product3">
                            <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
                            <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
                                <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
                                <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity3" id="quantity3" type="text" /></td>

                      </tr>

     <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box-header">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="sub" type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No part of this question has anything to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.  And you cannot run a Code Snippet on this page if it contains PHP.  JavaScript, CSS, and HTML only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're splitting the id but on your selector, you're not including it.

The correct way is

`$('#quantity' + numberPart[1]).prop('required', true);`

```js
$('.productSelect').change(function() {

  var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
  var numberPart = elementID.split("t", 2);

  if ($(this).val() != null) {
    $('#quantity' + numberPart[1]).prop('required', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/order/addOrder" method="post" role="form" id="orderform">

  <tr>

    <td>
      <select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product1" style="width: 100%" id="product1">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
        <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" type="text" /></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product2" style="width: 100%" id="product2">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
        <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity2" id="quantity2" type="text" /></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product3" style="width: 100%" id="product3">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
        <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity3" id="quantity3" type="text" /></td>

  </tr>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box-header">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="sub" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working perfectly. Above comment also contain the same answer as yours

Answer (score 1):

Split produces an array with the values before and after the splitting parameter.

That means numberpart is an array, if you log it looks like this:

```
(2) ["produc", "1"]
```

The value you are looking for is therefore "numberPart[1]"

```
$('.productSelect').change(function () {

  var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
  var numberPart = elementID.split("t", 2);

  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity'+ numberPart[1]).prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working perfectly fine. You made my day